# GetPropList with TRectangle returns StrokeThickness as property which should be part of Stroke class

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10-seattle

I'm using Delphi Seattle Update1 Win64 and trying to extract properties using RTTI.  My objective is to serialize component properties to JSON because I need to use this information in a non-Delphi environment.

My question is about `GetPropList` for a `TRectangle` (example) and why it returns properties that then cannot be passed to `GetPropValue`, namely:

1. `StrokeThickness` as type `tkFloat`
2. `StrokeCap` as type `tkEnumeration`
3. `StrokeDash` as type `tkEnumeration`
4. `StrokeJoin` as type tkEnumeration.

`GetPropList` does correctly returns `Stroke` as type `tkClass`, which is what I would have expected, and when parsed, Stroke class return `Thickness`, `Cap`, `Dash` and `Join` and I can get the correct values from these.

The problem is that executing `GetPropValue` on `StrokeThickness` causes an exception.  I therefore have to special case the "broken" properties returned by `GetPropList` which I would like to avoid.

At first I thought this was a problem with GetPropList returning a property that did not exist but I can execute the following in code and they both work:

```
   Rectangle1.StrokeThickness := 5;   //works

   Rectangle1.Stroke.Thickness := 10; //and also works
```

Other properties of type tkFloat or tkEnumeration work as expected and return the correct values.

I created a small test app to try to debug this.  What I found is that in the case of StrokeThickness, M.Code is nil in the function System.TypeInfo.TPropSet.GetProp (line 2397) which I guess explains why is causes an exception.

Attached is test code that I created to confirm what I was seeing in my bigger project.  How would I handle the four properties listed above without special case.

The form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 202
  ClientWidth = 542
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Rectangle1: TRectangle
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 97.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 97.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
  end
  object StrokeThickness: TButton
    Position.X = 40.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 144.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 97.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'RTTI'
    OnClick = StrokeThicknessClick
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Touch.InteractiveGestures = [Pan, LongTap, DoubleTap]
    DataDetectorTypes = []
    Position.X = 152.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 353.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 129.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
    Viewport.Width = 349.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 125.000000000000000000
  end
end
```

The test code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, FMX.Objects, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    StrokeThickness: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure StrokeThicknessClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses System.TypInfo;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.StrokeThicknessClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vValue : String;
  PropList : PPropList;
  PropInfo : PPropInfo;
  PropType : PPTypeInfo;
  PropListCount : Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
   memo1.Lines.Clear;

   PropListCount := GetPropList(Rectangle1, PropList);

   for I := 0 to PropListCount-1 do
   begin
     PropInfo := PropList^[I];
     PropType := PropInfo^.PropType;

     Memo1.Lines.Add('Name: '+String(PropInfo^.Name) );
     Memo1.Lines.Add('PropType: '+String(PropInfo^.PropType^.Name) );
     Memo1.Lines.Add('PropKind: '+GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TTypeKind), Ord(PropType^.Kind)) );
     Memo1.Lines.Add('');
   end;

   vValue := GetPropValue(Rectangle1, 'Name');               //test string
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Proprty Name = '+VarToStr(vValue) );

   vValue := GetPropValue(Rectangle1, 'Height');             //test float
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Property Height = '+VarToStr(vValue) );

   vValue := GetPropValue(Rectangle1, 'Sides');             //test enumeration
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Property Sides = '+VarToStr(vValue) );

   //The following would cause an exception
   {
   vValue := GetPropValue(Rectangle1, 'StrokeThickness');
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Property StrokeThickness ='+VarToStr(vValue));
   }

   Rectangle1.StrokeThickness := 5;   //works ??

   //Still fails after it was explicitly set
   {
   vValue := GetPropValue(Rectangle1, 'StrokeThickness');
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Property StrokeThickness ='+VarToStr(vValue));
   }

   Rectangle1.Stroke.Thickness := 10; //and also works... as expected

   //The following with cause an exception
   {
   vValue := GetPropValue(Rectangle1, 'StrokeDash');
   Memo1.Lines.Add('StrokeDash = '+VarToStr(vValue) );
   }

end;

end.
```

Comment: File a bug report with [QualityPortal](http://quality.embarcadero.com), and then try switching to new-style RTTI from the `System.Rtti` unit instead of using old-style RTTI from the `System.TypInfo` unit, see if it crashes on the same property.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks; will do.  Good to get a confirmation that I wasn't doing something wrong form someone with more experience before I submit a bug.  And I will fork and test with `System.Rtti` but I read that it bloated code size somewhat so I went with `System.TypInfo` instead.  I'll compare to see if there is any impact.

Comment: I'm not confirming or denying whether it is a bug, as I have not had a chance to try it myself yet. But it does sound like a bug, and it does not hurt to report it, you can always close it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use code like

```
var
  LProperty: TRttiProperty;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LArray: TArray<TRttiProperty>;
begin
  LContext := TRTTIContext.Create;
  LType := LContext.GetType(TRectangle);
  LArray := LType.GetDeclaredProperties;
  for LProperty in LArray do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Name: ' + LProperty.Name);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('PropType: ' + LProperty.PropertyType.Name);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('PropKind: ' + GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TTypeKind), Ord(LProperty.PropertyType.TypeKind)));
    if LProperty.IsReadable then
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Value: ' + LProperty.GetValue(Rectangle1).ToString);
    end
    else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Value of the property cannot be read');
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too short. So, the reason of the problem of the author was the fact that the properties StrokeThickness, StrokeCap, StrokeDash and
StrokeJoin are write-only. That's why the exception happens on attempt to read their values. So, the solution is to check whether the property can be read or no. At the moment I don't know how to do this using PPTypeInfo - I see there no suitable information. In the similar case in my own project I use System.Rtti unit and TRttiProperty which provides required check  LProperty.IsReadable